# Need formula for solving simple arithmetic problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Math gurus,
I feel a bit silly posting this, especially on this site-- but I simply can't remember what formula is used to solve the following problem:

If I have $12,500.00 as the net amount after 35% is taken from the gross sum, what is the gross sum?

I know that it is roughly $19,500.00, but I don't recall the formula to get there. Anyone willing to refresh my memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple proportion $\frac{12,500.00}{100-35}=\frac{x}{100}$, $x=\frac{12,500.00 \cdot 100}{65}$

Answer (score 1):

If the gross amount is $x$, then the net amount is $0.65x$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks John! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have left $12,500.00$ is the $65$% of the starting amount $X$.

Then, you have

$$12,500.00 = \frac{65}{100}\cdot X$$

Can you take it from here?